# Amazon polly branding on WordPress blog post audio version

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I recently configured my blog with Amazon Polly plugin. And it is working perfectly.

But the problem is it is showing 'Voiced by Amazon Polly' under the audio player. How can I remove it?

You can observe it [here.](https://raghunath.pw/its-easy-to-feel-overwhelming-just-do-your-work/)

Note: I'm using AWS free tier.

Answer (score 0):

That image is being inserted within the Polly Plugin.

You could probably modify the code to remove it, if it does not violate the license terms.

See: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/amazon-polly/trunk/public/class-amazonpolly-public.php

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
    $image         = 'https://d12ee1u74lotna.cloudfront.net/images/Voiced_by_Amazon_Polly_EN.png';
    $voice_by_part = '<a href="https://aws.amazon.com/polly/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src=" ' . $image . '" width="100" ></a>';
} else {
    $voice_by_part = '';
}
```